# Curious about your candidate score for the election?

Tags: discussion, election

[Shog9 created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289504/1161309) a SEDE query a few years back. I've changed just the site and the prefills; just enter your ID

http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=

Comment: I'd just like to say that candidate score is not everything! So don't worry too much about your candidate score, and don't over-value it either.

Comment: My score is still under 40 after all this time. Don't worry about the score. It's just a rough metric ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current candidates user ID's Added:

http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=18427,42401,37660,42632,52915,31503,507

Comment: I'm gonna accept just to mark this closed